# Excel: Links to a Sharepoint picture require login

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

We have some pictures in a sharepoint group that are shared via a link (anonymous view is enabled). Those links work fine when you open them directly in the browser.

When you put this hyperlink in an excel spreadsheat so that the user can click on it, the user will then have to login to https://login.microsoftonline.com and can't view the image.

But if we copy the link location from the excel spreadsheet and paste them in the browser, it works.

So for some reason, the link works differently when being clicked in excel vs. being pasted in the browser.
This happens with chrome and IE11.

Can any explain why this is, or tell me how to overcome the problem?

Comment: Im guessing even with anonymous view you still have to be a member of the organization from which the team site or share point is associated, your browser may have your credentials saved hence not needing the login, but I am still learning sharepoint myself so this is really just a guess